# generate xarray.Dataset image subplots

Tags: python, python-xarray, hvplot

Setup is a `xarray.Dataset` with two variables and a grid of values.

```py
import xarray as xr
import numpy as np
import hvplot.xarray

ds = xr.Dataset({
    'temp': (('lon', 'lat'), 15 + 8 * np.random.randn(2, 2)),
    'precip': (('lon', 'lat'), 10 * np.random.rand(2, 2)),
    },
    coords={
        'lon': [-99.83, -99.32],
        'lat': [42.25, 42.21],
    })
```

Extrapolating from the [hvplot docs](https://hvplot.pyviz.org/user_guide/Subplots.html), I expected subplots for each variable and a shared colorbar (z-axis) would result from:

```py
ds.hvplot(z=['temp', 'precip'], subplots=True)
```

That gives an `UnboundLocalError` and several variants are no better. Am I doing it wrong or is it not implemented? If that latter, any way to manually produce two `hvplot.image` plots side-by-side with a shared colorbar?

Comment: I can reproduce the `UnboundLocalError` and have raised an issue on hvplot: https://github.com/pyviz/hvplot/issues/336 . I would have thought that `ds.hvplot(z='temp') + ds.hvplot(z='precip')` would be enough to get the colorbar ranges to be shared, but it doesn't look like that's the case.